# Is every irreducible subfactor planar algebra a quotient of the planar algebra of tangles?

Tags: subfactors, planar-algebras

Let $\mathcal{T}_{n,\pm}$ be the vector space generated by the planar tangles (up to isomorphism) having $2n$ intervals on their "ouput'' disk and a white (or black) shaded marked interval. Then the family of vector spaces $(\mathcal{T}_{n,\pm})_{n=0,1, \ \dots}$ admits a natural planar $*$-algebra structure because the planar tangles act on themselves by planar composition and have an involution by horizontal reflexion.

Analogically, a finite group $G$ acts on itself by left multiplication: it's the left regular representation $V$.
But every irreducible representation of $G$ is a quotient of $V$.

*Question:* Is every irreducible subfactor planar algebra a quotient of $(\mathcal{T}_{n,\pm})$?

This is a  planar tangle in $\mathcal{T}_{4,+}$, [image]
with seven "inputs" disks numbered from $1$ to $7$.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question, but the planar algebra you describe (after possibly quotienting out vectors with trace 0) seems to be the Temperley-Lieb-Jones planar algebra. Every subfactor planar algebra contains a TLJ planar algebra as a subalgebra.

Comment: @MarcelBischoff: The TLJ planar algebra is the planar algebra of tangles *without* "input" disk.

Comment: So I misunderstood... you are not saying anything about an input disk.

Comment: @MarcelBischoff:  the "input" disks are the disks inside the "output" disk (i.e. the small disks inside the big disk), see the picture edited.

Comment: I still don't get the analogy with groups, it is about representations of groups while your question seems to be about presentations of planar algebras!?! About your question: for finite depth shouldn't this follow (with a bit of work) from http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.4577 ?

Comment: Yes, this should work for the finite depth case. About the analogy: a planar algebra is a representation of the planar operad which also acts on itself, as a group acts on itself. The irreducibility of a group representation, and of a subfactor, have a meaning in term of an irreducible bimodule. The analogy could stop there.